# Get data from Android HTTP Post

Tags: java, android, servlets, google-cloud-messaging

*There are two sides in my application; 1> gcmserver & 2> AppDevice and I'm using google's GCM in my application(both gcmserver & AppDevice) + using two different systems(one for gcmserver ,another for AppDevice).*

Now the **issue** is:

*To my server end there is java page(http://192.168.1.111:8080/gcmserver/HomeServlet.java).
[192.168.1.111(i.e gcmserver) is my localhost] and I'm using Tomcat 6.0.35*

And I'm assigning values in that page from AppDevice side using this piece of code:

```
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("employeeid", getempid));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", getpsssword));
//          String URL_STRING="http://192.168.0.151:8080/map/jsp/passwordget.jsp";
            String URL_STRING="http://192.168.1.111:8080/gcmserver/HomeServlet.java";

            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL_STRING);
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);
```

*Now I exactly want to retrive the value from this page whatever is assigning to it (here:"employeeid","password").*

Is their any way to achieve these values from this page or should I have to use use *`Jsoup`* for it ......//